# "They did not pay any attention" vs "They paid no attention"

Tags: sentence-construction, difference

I made two sentences:
1. "They did not pay any attention"
2. "They paid no attention"

**Q1: Are they both correct?**
**Q2: What's the difference between these two sentences.**
**Q3: Which expression is better and when to use it?**

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The two sentences are both valid and good English. Both are commonly used by fluent speakers. They mean pretty much the same thing. I haven't checked any statistics, but I'd guess that #1 is more common. #2 sounds a little more formal. But either is fine.